# Apply multiple patches at different levels

Tags: patch

I am trying to apply patches for multiple files. These files are present in different directories at different levels in a top-level directory. The directory structure is same for the patch files also.

Is there any way in which I can apply all patches at once?

I'm applying them individually using patch -p1 command.

Comment: What's the exact command you're using?

Comment: right now i'm iterating to each folder in which the patch file is present and applying it using 
"   patch -p1 <file.patch  "

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
find . -iname '*.patch' -execdir sh -c 'patch -p1 < $0' {} \;
```

This `find` command:

- looks for files in the current directory (`.`) recursively
- that are have filenames ending in `.patch` (adjust according to whatever naming pattern your patch files follow)
- and in the directory where a matching file was found, runs `sh -c 'patch -p1 < $0' matched-file`:

  - `$0` is the first argument, which is the matched file, so the command is essentially `patch -p1 < matched-file`
  - `sh -c` is needed since we're using redirection.